# Big-Oh for size of a Sperner family

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

I'm developing an algorithm that will generate a collection of subsets of a ground set having the property that no subset in the collection is a subset of any other, and I'd like to give a Big-Oh bound on the number of subsets there might be in the worst case.

From some basic research it seems that this is given by [Sperner's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem), which says that the maximum number of such subsets of an $n$-element subset is $n \choose {\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}$.  It's good to have that bound, but I don't recall ever seeing a Big-Oh expression that used the binomial coefficient, so I'm wondering if there's a reasonably tight upper bound in terms of the "usual" functions used in Big-Oh.  It's clearly $\textrm O(2^n)$, but is there something tighter?

(For comparison, the "most natural" lower bound for sorting $n$ elements using comparisons is $\Omega(n!)$, but this is invariably written as $\Omega(n \log n)$, which is asymptotically equivalent on account of Stirling's approximation.)

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) could be used to get $\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ (says much more than big-Oh)

Comment: @talegari: Thanks!  From that I get ${k \choose \lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \sim \frac{2^{k+1/2}}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$.